# Is there a way to control safari mouse swipe gestures?

Tags: macos, safari, mouse, swipe, gesture

In the latest version of OSX and safari you can use mouse swipe gestures to go forwards and backwards through your browser history. my problem: I have a page with a horizontally scrolling image gallery. If you're using the mouse swipe gesture to scroll through the images, when you get to the end of the images its very easy to swipe into the next or previous page...

does anyone know a way to explicitly disable this using css or any other method?

Comment: It's not clear from what point-of-view you're trying to disable this.  Do you want to disable this from the website's point-of-view (with web "technologies") or directly on the client's machine (somehow messing with Safari and/or the system)?  Or does it matter?

Comment: websites point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following documents can help:

- [Handling Gesture Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW23)
- [Preventing Default Behaviour](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW24)
  : with  `event.preventDefault();`

These might only apply to iOS though.

Aside from that, I would say it's just how the browser handles the gestures, similar to how mouse-wheel scrolling will scroll a DIV block until it reaches the end then start to scroll the page as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to prevent this behaviour since it's a browser gesture (`event.preventDefault()` on `touchstart` event won't work).